# Remove partially duplicated rows in SQL Server Express

Tags: sql-server, duplicates

Got a table with several columns, with date at the end. It looks like:

```
Col1   Col2   Col3   date
-----+------+------+------------
  x     y      z     2022-10-01
  x     y      z     2022-10-10
  a     b      c     2022-10-01
  a     b      b     2022-10-10
  w     u      c     2022-10-15
```

What I'm trying to do is remove duplicates based on first three columns. With latest date left in column 4.

Tried to list it with:

```
Select col1, col2, col3, count(*) as counter 
from database
group by col1, col2, col3, date 
having count (*) > 1;
```

It's not working because it counts each row, including different dates.. Haven't found any other clues

Expected output is:

| Col1 | Col2 | Col3 | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| x | y | z | 2022-10-10 |
| a | b | c | 2022-10-10 |
| w | u | c | 2022-10-15 |

Comment: Please add the expected output to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a common table expression and `ROW_NUMBER` to achieve this:

```
WITH cte 
AS
(
SELECT col1, col2, col3, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY col1, col2, col3 ORDER BY date) as rn
from database
)
DELETE cte
WHERE rn>1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just aggregate by the first 3 columns and take the max of the fourth:

```sql
SELECT col1, col2, col3, MAX(date) AS date
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY col1, col2, col3;
```

Comment: Well, it will list all rows with max date, however it's not filtering duplicated rows. So 'drop' will remove not duplicated rows as well